# Need a loader everytime when click on new link on webview in android app

Tags: android, android-layout, webview, android-webview

I want a loader to be displayed every time when I clicked on any link inside webview.

currently at `application start` only it is showing me `loader`.

used following code

> some time for every load loader is coming sometimes not , not sure why it is happening.

```
// Force links and redirects to open in the WebView instead of in a browser
    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {      
            ProgressDialog progressDialog = null;

        //If you will not use this method url links are opeen in new brower not in webview
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {    
     if (progressDialog == null) {
                // in standard case YourActivity.this
                progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
                progressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
                progressDialog.show();
            }          
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }

        //Show loader on url load
        public void onLoadResource (WebView view, String url) {
            if (progressDialog == null) {
                // in standard case YourActivity.this
                progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
                progressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
                progressDialog.show();
            }
        }


        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            try{
            if (progressDialog.isShowing()) {
                progressDialog.dismiss();
                progressDialog = null;
            }   
            }
            catch(Exception exception){
                exception.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        //Show error page
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
            mWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/error.html");
        }             
    }); 

     // Javascript enabled on webview  
    mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);         



    //Load url in webview
    mWebView.loadUrl(url);

}
```

Comment: are you nulling the `progressDialog` variable somewhere? Because without that, your if will be true only once...

Comment: nope updated question with full code please advice

Comment: where are you dismissing your dialog? Where are you nulling your progressDialog variable? If you have experience in c# like your profile suggest, you should be able to understand why your if check is only once true...

Comment: I got I did the same way please check updated code in question.
I did it in onPageFinished

Comment: I do not have any experiencein android so do not know how exactly webview works , can you help me to show loader on every click

Comment: Catching a nullpointer with a try/catch... nice. Bad practice! Anyway have you tried to override the `shouldOverrideUrlLoading()` method? That should be triggered on each url request. Beside that, try to debug and see if the `onLoadResource()` is called on each load!?

Comment: I guess in c# you do debugging as well, right? Try it!

Comment: So please share your solution as an answer so you can accept in two days.

Comment: @Override
shouldOverrideUrlLoading() this method but still after 2 clicks it is not showing any loader :/

Comment: you should than update the question and show your complete code of the WebViewClient...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Try This:**

```
   @Override
   public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {    
   if (progressDialog == null) {
            // in standard case YourActivity.this
            progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            progressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
            progressDialog.show();
        }          
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }

  @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {

        super.onPageFinished(view, url);
        try {

            if (progressDialog .isShowing()) {

                progressDialog .dismiss();

                progressDialog = null;

            }

        } catch (Exception exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

 @Override
 public void onLoadResource (WebView view, String url) {

 }

 public void onPageStarted(WebView webView, String url, Bitmap favicon) {

        super.onPageStarted(webView, url, favicon);

        if (progressDialog == null) {
            // in standard case YourActivity.this
            progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            progressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
            progressDialog.show();
        }            

 }
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of issues I can spot in your code.

1. Please do not call `WebView.loadUrl` from `shouldOverrideUrlLoading`. It's not needed, and in fact creates a loop. The load is already in progress.
2. Please show the dialog from the `onPageStarted` callback, and dismiss it from `onPageFinished` (like you are now). `onLoadResource` and `onShouldOverrideUrlLoading` aren't the right places to display it for the effect you are looking for.

Hope this helps!